# How to populate a recursive m2m field

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, recursive-datastructures

I have a class in my model with a recursive m2m field

My `model.py`:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=64)
    slug = models.SlugField(primary_key=True)
    friends = models.ManyToManyField('self', 
        related_name='nation_friends', symmetrical=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Person, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I populate my database with a script. The problem comes when an instance has references to not yet created instances

My `script.py`:

```
john = add_person('John', ['marc', 'philip'])
#john = add_person('John', [marc, philip]) #this gives immediately error: marc is not definited
marc = add_person('Marc', [])
philip = add_person('Philip', [])

def add_person(name, friends):
    p=Person.objects.get_or_create(name=name)[0]
    lista_friends = []
    for f in friends:
        lista_friends.append(f)
    p.friends.set(lista_friends)
```

This is the error (my translation, below the original)

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: ERROR:  the INSERT or the UPDATE on the
table "core_person_friends" break the constrain of external key "core_person_friends_to_person_id_ab3c358a_fk_core_person_slug"
DETAIL:  The key (to_person_id)=(marc) is not present on the table "core_person".
```

original:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: ERRORE:  la INSERT o l'UPDATE sulla 
tabella "core_person_friends" viola il vincolo di chiave esterna "core_person_friends_to_person_id_ab3c358a_fk_core_person_slug"
DETAIL:  La chiave (to_person_id)=(marc) non ?? presente nella tabella "core_person".
```

Maybe the problem is because the slug field?

Answer (score 1):

You should pass a list of objects, not just values. Get the `Person` objects by their name and add those objects. You are trying to add person names. Also make sure names have the same case, otherwise instances will be created multiple times for same person.

```
john = add_person('John', ['Marc', 'Philip'])
marc = add_person('Marc', [])
philip = add_person('Philip', [])

def add_person(name, friends):
    p = Person.objects.get_or_create(name=name)[0]
    lista_friends = []
    for f in friends:
        lista_friends.append(Person.objects.get_or_create(name=f)[0])
    p.friends.set(lista_friends)
```